# Scrapy and logging

Tags: logging, scrapy

I've setup a number of loggers with config file and they all write not only to file but also to console and with the same format used by Scrapy. I need some logs to be written to a file only.

The above happens if I call `logging.config.fileConfig()` before `CrawlerProcess()`. If I move it after, I see the opposite: no logging to console neither from my loggers nor from scarpy (while writing to file still ok).

```
  init_logging() #here

  settings = get_project_settings()
  process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
#.. or here
  process.crawl(MySpider)
  process.start()
```

Comment: if you run your spider like this `scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_ENABLED=False` does it write into your file?

Comment: This way it fails to start

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 142, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 211, in __init__
    configure_logging(self.settings)
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/log.py", line 100, in configure_logging

Comment: handler = _get_handler(settings)
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/log.py", line 110, in _get_handler
    elif settings.getbool('LOG_ENABLED'):
  File "/home/serj/work/mirror0/virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 71, in getbool
    return bool(int(self.get(name, default)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'False'

Comment: that command line is outdated, my bad, try `scrapy crawl myspider --nolog`

Comment: in this case no loggers are able to reach console. And writing to file stops as well.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is this http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#module-scrapy.utils.log

Comment: Yes describe similar use case and suggest configure logging in the following oreder: `configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig()`  But it does not help. Apparently CrawlerProcess installs another root handler.

Comment: [`CrawlerProcess` does configure logging](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/crawler.py#L240) with `install_root_handler=True` (default), so you can try using [`CrawlerRunner`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=CrawlerRunner#run-scrapy-from-a-script) instead, where you configure logging yourself

Comment: Switching to `CrawlerRunner` helps in that relation I can make my loggers work correctly. But now I can't make Scrapy logging work. The only way to see some log messages i have to make `getLogger("scrapy").addHanlder(StreamHandler(...))`. The problem is that this way I get SOME messages. The other part of them is not shown, and logging level is not the problem. Errors are suppressed, so this is not a working solution.